# Traversing a uncalculable nested array backwards, node traversal - Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I have an object that has a structure like so

```
{
    this.parent: undefined,
    this.nodes: []
}
```

Inside `nodes` can be any number of objects with the same structure, but there parent would be set to that of the object that has the nodes array as its property. As the object follows this pattern the top level object could have nested nodes which are potentially quite deep.

I would like to add a method to the top level object that will search all of the nodes in reverse. An example of what I am trying to achieve is below except that this function is searching forward.

```
{
     this.parent: undefined,
     this.nodes: [],

     this.searchForward: function() {

         this.nodes.forEach(function(node) {

             this.searchForward.call(this, node);
         }, this);
     }
}
```

The `searchForward` function above will search all nodes to as deep as they can go, and then move onto the next node in line etc etc etc.

I am trying to write a function that will recursively search from the deepest child back to the parent (essentially the above in reverse).

Any ideas to get me started would be great, thank you.

Comment: Do you mean to search from the deepest child back to the parent?

Comment: Yes, I will edit my question, I was having a hard time explaining it.

Comment: But that object doesn't look right, is that a constructor or what is it because that isn't a literal object...

Comment: I just typed it up quick

Comment: @user2251919, could you type up a sample object? Would be much easier for us to try fiddling with it on http://jsfiddle.net while searching for a solution.

Comment: @Dogbert am on it now

Comment: @user2251919, also, for `potentially quite deep`, how deep could it be? Simple-recursion-can-blow-up-the-stack deep?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if all you want is to traverse the path back up to the root, that's simple.  (I'm pretty sure that's not what you want, though.)

```
this.searchUp: function() {
    var parnt = this.parent;
    while (parnt) {
        // do something, if you want
        parnt = parnt.parnt;
    }
}
```

The first thing I considered would be to call `searchForward` in the "do something" section.  That could work, but strikes me as inefficient - each time you go up another parent, you'll search through nodes you've already searched.  Still, that on its own should work.  (As long as you're calling searchForward from searchUp, there's no risk of an infinite loop.)

We can make it a bit more complex and avoid the redundancy simply by adding a flag.  You'd need to modify `searchForward` and make a function similar to it:

```
this.initializeSearched: function() {
     this.nodes.forEach(function(node) {
         this.searched = false;
         this.initializeSearched.call(this, node);
     }, this);
 }
this.searchForward: function() {
     this.nodes.forEach(function(node) {
         if (this.searched) { continue; }
         this.searchForward.call(this, node);
     }, this);
 }
```

Once you have this, you should be able to just put `searchForward` in the "do something" section of `searchUp` and be done.

Comment: This is awesome, I will try to implement it, and let you know how I get on!